# Getting error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can anyone help me with this:

I need to display dynamic data in my `_DeliveryDetailsPatial.cshtml`. This is called every time the user is in the Delivery Information page or New Address page. Every time I am to navigate to either of these pages i keep getting this ERROR:

> Object reference not set to an instannce of an object

How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Here's my code:

`_DeliveryDrtailsPartial`:

```
@model QuiznosOnlineOrdering.Models.StoreViewModel
<table id="orderTable" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="t">Item</td>
            <td class="t">Quantity</td>
            <td class="t">Item Price</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.StoreAddress)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.NOM)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ADRESSE)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.VILLE)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

`StoreViewModel`:

```
    public IEnumerable<Store> StoreAddress { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StoreHour> StoreHour { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReferenceAcceptedPayment> StoreAcceptedPayment { get; set; }
```

`DeliveryController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStoreDetails()
{
    StoreViewModel store = new StoreViewModel();
    store.StoreAddress = from s in db.Store
                             select s;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: post the full stack trace please but offhand guessing it has to do with the fact that Model.StoreAddress is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStoreDetails()
{
    StoreViewModel store = new StoreViewModel();
    store.StoreAddress = from s in db.Store
                             select s;

    return View(store);
}
```

You haven't passed model

Comment: thanks the data i need from the database are now being displayed. But I get another error, when I click a button (HttpPost), I still get the same Error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are never actually injecting the model into the view.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStoreDetails()
{
    StoreViewModel store = new StoreViewModel();
    store.StoreAddress = from s in db.Store
                             select s;

    return View(store);
}
```

As a result, when you try to read properties on your model, you get an exception since the model is null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the model like this

```
    [HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStoreDetails()
{
    StoreViewModel store = new StoreViewModel();
    store.StoreAddress = from s in db.Store
                             select s;

    return View(store);
}
```

Also following are the links which will help you also in passing views to partial view also.

```
 return PartialView("_ViewPage",model);
```

[Setting models in asp.net mvc views and partial views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698246/ASP-NET-MVC-Special-Views-Partial-View-and-Layout)